# Странная магия оптимизатора MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть временная таблица следующего вида:

[image: временная таблица]

```
CREATE TABLE #1 (
    num1 FLOAT
    ,num2 FLOAT
    )
INSERT INTO #1
SELECT 0
    ,0
INSERT INTO #1
SELECT 0
    ,1
INSERT INTO #1
SELECT 1
    ,0
INSERT INTO #1
SELECT 1
    ,1
```

Выполняю следующий запрос и он валится с ошибкой:

```
SELECT *
FROM #1 a
WHERE (
        a.num1 > 0
        AND a.num2 = 0
        )
    OR (
        a.num1 > 0
        AND a.num2 > 0
        AND a.num1 / a.num2 >= 2
        )
    OR (
        a.num1 >= 0
        AND a.num2 < 0
        )
```

> Divide by zero error encountered.

Покурил справку, там написано, что операция деления выполняется раньше всех логических операций. Ок, теперь стало понятно, почему валится с ошибкой. 
Но потом я убираю знак "=" из последнего условия и все работает:

```
SELECT *
FROM #1 a
WHERE (
        a.num1 > 0
        AND a.num2 = 0
        )
    OR (
        a.num1 > 0
        AND a.num2 > 0
        AND a.num1 / a.num2 >= 2
        )
    OR (
        a.num1 > 0
        AND a.num2 < 0
        )
```

Посмотрел план выполнения запроса:
[image: план выполнения]

Судя по плану выполнения запроса, должна была снова возникнуть ошибка деления на ноль. Но этого не произошло. Проверял на Microsoft SQL Server-е версии 2005 и 2012. Проблема такая везде присутствует. В Teradata первый запрос отрабатывает без проблем.

Мой вопрос не в том, как переписать запрос, чтобы все заработало, а ПОЧЕМУ оно так работает. Почему, когда во втором запросе я убираю знак "=" запрос отрабатывает без проблем?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

По-видимому дело вот в чём.

Посмотрите план выполнения (XML). Когда вы убираете `=`, то предикат оптимизируется в (отредактировано для краткости)

```xml
<Predicate>
    <ScalarOperator ScalarString="...">
        <Logical Operation="AND">
            <ScalarOperator>
                num1 > 0
            </ScalarOperator>
            <ScalarOperator>
                <Logical Operation="OR">
                    <ScalarOperator>
                        num2 = 0
                    </ScalarOperator>
                    <ScalarOperator>
                        num1 / num2 >= 2 AND num2 > 0
                    </ScalarOperator>
                    <ScalarOperator>
                        num2 < 0
                    </ScalarOperator>
                </Logical>
            </ScalarOperator>
        </Logical>
    </ScalarOperator>
</Predicate>
```

т.е.

```sql
a.num1 > 0
AND
(
    a.num2 = 0
    OR
    a.num1 / a.num2 >= 2 AND a.num2 > 0
    OR
    a.num2 < 0
)
```

Строки данных `(0, 0)` и `(0, 1)` отсекаются по условию `a.num1 > 0`. Строки `(1, 0)` и `(1, 1)` ему удовлетворяет, но `(1, 0)` проходит по условию `a.num2 = 0` (до деления не доходит). Строка `(1, 1)` не проходит ни по одному условию OR.

Для сравнения, в неизменённом запросе предикат (также отредактировано для краткости), взятый из оценочного плана запроса, выглядит так:

```xml
<Predicate>
    <ScalarOperator ScalarString="...">
        <Logical Operation="OR">
            <ScalarOperator>
                num1 > 0 AND num2 = 0
            </ScalarOperator>
            <ScalarOperator>
                num1/num2 >= 2 AND num1 > 0 AND num2 > 0
            </ScalarOperator>
            <ScalarOperator>
                num1 >= 0 AND num2 < 0
            </ScalarOperator>
        </Logical>
    </ScalarOperator>
</Predicate>
```

Comment: Спасибо за такой подробный ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Из плана видно, что значения трактуются как вещественные. Вещественное деление на ноль приводит к результату NaN (не число).

В то время как челочисленное деление на ноль приводит к ошибке Divide by zero.

Вероятно, сравнение `>` трактуется как неточное сравнение с нулём, отсюда вещественные числа. А сравнение `>=` трактуется как точное сравнение, отсюда челые числа.